# Blazor, There is no tracked object with id 'x'. Perhaps the DotNetObjectReference instance was already disposed

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side

I have an editable form, at first component render, everything is OK, but when I leave the page and return back, it raises "There is no tracked object with id 'x'. Perhaps the DotNetObjectReference instance was already disposed."

OnAfterRenderAsync Method :

```
 private DotNetObjectReference<Groups> _objRef;

protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    if (firstRender)
    {
        _objRef = DotNetObjectReference.Create(this);
        await JSRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("JSFun", _objRef);
    }
}
```

JSInvoke Method :

```
[JSInvokable]
public void UpdateModel(string Id)
{
    Group = GroupService.Get(new Guid(Id));
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

Dispose Method :

```
public void Dispose()
{
     _objRef?.Dispose();
}
```

Javascript Method : **(Here in the second page render the error raises)**

```
$(document).on('click', '.btnEdit', function () {       
    instance.invokeMethodAsync('UpdateModel', Id).then(c => {         
        editModal.modal('show');
    });
});
```

---

- **Update**
  I solve the problem by changing the event handler from $(document).on('click' to wrapperInstance.on('click' where wrapperInstance is a wrapper to my current component :

  var wrapper = $("#wrapper");
  wrapper.removeClass();
  wrapper.addClass("wrapper" + instance["_id"]);
  var wrapperInstance = $(".wrapper" + instance["_id"]);

note that I have added a wrapper to my component like this :

```
<div id="wrapper">
  component content
</div>
```

Comment: It's not a great idea to  mix JS dom manipulation with Blazor, but let's assume you know what you are doing and just ask - what happens in JSFun?

Comment: How do u say that it is not a great idea? A Blazor app can invoke JavaScript functions from .NET methods and .NET methods from JavaScript functions.

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19542